# efxclipse convert svg to fxml working? Not for me

Tags: svg, javafx, efxclipse

I was just wondering if anyone did convert an svg to fxml. I do right click on svg file Convert... nothing happens. What's the trick? 
The Svg file is saved as plain svg file in inkscape.
thanks for input
regards Chris

Comment: Note that Inkscape SVG is a super set of true SVG